# how to grep only current directory for specific files

Tags: bash, grep

Hello I have a question I want to find a keyword in a directory without recursion. And I want to check only for the .c extensions.
For example I try;

```
grep -r 'keyword' --include=*.c .
```

And it works. But I dont want recursive search I just want the current directory's results so I remove the -r

```
grep 'keyword' --include=*.c .
```

However this gives me an error that ". is a directory". Actually I have an idea to write the contents of recursive grep to a textfile and grep that textfile for the file extensions but I think it wont be efficient at all. Thanks for your support.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Questions about basic use of the Unix command line belong on Unix.SE or SuperUser.com.

Comment: --include only works with -r

Comment: @Novaterata-- do you have a reference for this? The man pages do not seem to suggest that `--include` only works with the `-r` option, and it seems to work for me, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
grep 'keyword' *.c
```

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. I was overcomplicating the function. By the way for future searchers: to seek for multiple extensions in the directory you need to replace the *.c word with *.{c,h,c++}

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is clean and efficient.
But I have the feeling that you insist on using "-r" and/or "--include", maybe for reasons not mentioned.

```
bash-3.1$ grep -r --include="*.c" -dskip 'keyword' ./*
```

Answer (score 1):

Closer to your original syntax, you can use:

```
grep --include=*.c 'keyword' *
```

This reports directories without searching them.